# Reading in .xlsx

Tags: r

I have my working directory set and when I use this code for .xlsx:

```
files <- list.files(path = "foldername/", pattern = "*xlsx")
df <- read_excel(paste0("foldername/", files)
```

I receive an error that path must be a string. In other forms of writing the code I get path does not exist. When I run the same code for .xls it works fine. What could be happening? Thank you!

Comment: You mean `pattern = "*.xlsx")` ?

Comment: (1) `pattern=` is a regex, so while `"*xlsx"` works, a more specific (and regex-friendly) pattern could be `"\\.xlsx$"`. (2) Your code is missing a closing/right-paren, not sure if that's causing issues or you aren't sharing your real code. (3) A better practice is to use `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)` so that you don't have to subsequently `paste0("foldername/",.)` to it. (4) That error presents when `length(x) == 1 && is.character(x)` is not true, suggesting your `files` is not length exactly 1. Try `lapply(files, read_excel)` for a list of frames.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Yeah I forgot the extra bracket. I tried a few things with the special characters for regex friendliness, and full.names. Can't seem to get this going. It's insane because I'm at a part of my code where I need to scrub/test my output and now all files are in .xlsx. For some reason, everything works fine for .xls. So frustrating

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(xlsx)

setwd("..../excel_files")

files = list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
df <- lapply(files, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheetIndex = 1))

for (i in files) {
    df <- rbind(df, read.xlsx(i, sheetIndex = 1))
}
```

Comment: Thank for commenting. I tried this and I get - error in loadworkbook(file, password = password) - It seems it's a result of the df <- lapply line. No idea...